# Can chaining be abstracted in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, code-duplication, chain

I am writing a UI assertions test with cypress and I am seeing a lot of repeated chaining. Is there a way to abstract this out into a helper method for easier maintainability (and less code duplication)?

example code:

```
it('displays the table column headers', () => {
      DivisionPage.divisionNameColumnHeader()
        .should('be.visible')
        .and('have.css', 'text-transform', 'capitalize')
        .and('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(35, 40, 43)')
        .and('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(195, 202, 206)')
        .and('have.css', 'cursor', 'pointer')
        .and('have.css', 'font-family', '"Open Sans"')
        .and('have.css', 'position', 'sticky')
      DivisionPage.teamsColumnHeader()
        .should('be.visible')
        .and('have.css', 'text-transform', 'capitalize')
        .and('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(35, 40, 43)')
        .and('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(212, 217, 220)')
        .and('have.css', 'cursor', 'pointer')
        .and('have.css', 'font-family', '"Open Sans"')
        .and('have.css', 'position', 'sticky')
      DivisionPage.playersColumnHeader()
        .should('be.visible')
        .and('have.css', 'text-transform', 'capitalize')
        .and('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(35, 40, 43)')
        .and('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(212, 217, 220)')
        .and('have.css', 'cursor', 'pointer')
        .and('have.css', 'font-family', '"Open Sans"')
        .and('have.css', 'position', 'sticky')
})
```

Note that I am using page models so the `DivisionPage.divisionNameColumnHeader()` is equal to something like this: `cy.get('[data-cy="division-name-column-header"]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function or method is feasible, but a [Custom Command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands) is better since your repeated code is Cypress assertions.

A plus is these commands are global to all tests, if you define them in `/support/commands.js`.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('isStickyVisibleAndCapitalizedInCorporateColors',
  {prevSubject:true},
  (subject) => {
    cy.wrap(subject)
      .should('be.visible')
      .and('have.css', 'text-transform', 'capitalize')
      .and('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(35, 40, 43)')
      .and('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(212, 217, 220)')
      .and('have.css', 'cursor', 'pointer')
      .and('have.css', 'font-family', 'Open Sans')
      .and('have.css', 'position', 'sticky')
})

// Used like a composite assertion
DivisionPage.divisionNameColumnHeader().isStickyVisibleAndCapitalizedInCorporateColors()
```

Or select all elements at once and iterate the collection

```js
it('displays the table column headers', () => {

  cy.get('[data-cy="division-name-column-header"], [data-cy="division-teams-column-header"], [data-cy="division-players-column-header"]')
    .each($el => {
      cy.wrap($el)
        .should('be.visible')
        .and('have.css', 'text-transform', 'capitalize')
        .and('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(35, 40, 43)')
        .and('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(195, 202, 206)')
        .and('have.css', 'cursor', 'pointer')
        .and('have.css', 'font-family', '"Open Sans"')
        .and('have.css', 'position', 'sticky')
    })
})
```